# What makes a particular platform suitable or unsuitable for production use?

Tags: arduino, netduino, mbed, production

Let's assume that the cost of goods is an insignificant factor.  If a company lacks a team to produce a custom board for a particular product, but has success with an off-the shelf development platform like Arduino / Netduino / mbed, what sorts of things should be considered before going forward?

If I'm not mistaken, Arduino was originally targeting university students because of its low price and ease of use.  It naturally became a popular platform for artists and makers.  I see the Netduino as a logical extension of Arduino -- it allows people to use a robust and rich IDE (Visual Studio 2010) and get things done quickly via the .NET Micro Framework.  mbed is another nice hobbyist platform because of its ease of use, free tools (online compiler), and hardware peripherals.

So my question is, why shouldn't companies adopt these development platforms for production usage?  In other words, is it a bad idea to just buy several boards from Sparkfun, program each of them with the code, and then deploy the product to customers?

I'm specifically interested in Netduino, but arguments for / against Arduino and mbed are also welcome.  On the flip side, would you, or have you done this before?

I personally look at the Netduino development as a "core module" that other processor manufacturers sell for product integrations, but maybe I'm missing something important here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the things you might look at when sourcing a controller module are issue such as security of supply over time, any licensing issues, any inefficiencies in firmware loading process for production, any code security issues, and any manufacturing quality or regulatory compliance concerns.  Some of those are going to be more of a concern for a proprietary module than a relatively open one you could have someone else make an equivalent to or eventually merge with other functionality in your product.

Comment: Supply could be an issue, but at least the designs for *duino are open source.

Comment: @Dave - You missed the point.  Chris (I think) was talking mostly about problems with .NET, not with the hardware.

Comment: @reemrevnivek - hmm... sure sounded like hardware issues to me.  Why would supply issues, firmware loading, and mfg. quality have anything to do with .NET?

Comment: You may or may not be able to get a license to load a particular runtime on an alternate sourced board.  The various issues I was suggesting are an assortment not necessarily related to each other.

Answer (score 12):

Yikes!  Either you're thoroughly confused, or your idea of production is different from mine.  I consider production to mean selling a product to the general public in quantities of thousands or more, then supporting and updating the design.  Products which don't go to the general public are either internal or contract work, and products which sell in smaller quantities are special-purpose or otherwise different. 'Several boards from Sparkfun' wouldn't fulfill a production need.

First, the cost of goods is always a significant factor.  Just how significant it is may differ from product to product, and it may be less significant if the particular item is only a small component of a larger system which has been optimized for cost. However, in any environment where you're in competition with other producers (which you must be because if you're in government or have a monopoly you wouldn't be asking this question), cost will be a factor.  The $35 for the Netduino (in cost alone) could usually be reduced to $10 or less for most applications with a custom design.  If you are convinced that the cost doesn't matter, there are further reasons against buying such a design.

Yes, all three boards were designed for students, designers, and hobbyists.  They are designed to be reliable enough for a development kit which sits on a desk.  That student should know a few things about safe handling procedures which the general population does not know or practice.  Issues such as ESD, long-term power dissipation, and component derating were likely demoted below things which are less important for production like solderability and simplicity.

Your affinity for IDEs and prepackaged solutions is frightening.  In my opinion, you place way too much trust in your tool providers.  If the boards become more expensive, if the license terms are changed, if the server goes down, the software is declared obsolete, the board manufacturer goes out of business (etc. etc. etc...), your business is hosed.   Also, you lack an understanding of what's going on behind the scenes.  If something doesn't work the way the documentation says it should what is your plan? Your idea to buy a few Arduinos, program them, and deploy the product, for example, lacks any plan for code protection.  Someone else could copy your code out of the microcontroller, duplicate the relevant parts of the design for a third the price, and outsell you.
Relying on an IDE and language for the stuff you don't understand is a recipe for disaster.

Using a development kit in your design will make your product overpriced, fragile, bulky, power-hungry, and inefficient.  It will also be hard to debug, a pain to support, and you'll be at the mercy of your suppliers.  It will make you look incompetent.

However, all is not lost.  If you implement your design on a development board, it will be straightforward to have someone (either on or off your team) customize it to remove these deficiencies.  If you lack a team, you should hire one, bring in a contractor, or have it done by a design firm.

Comment: Production does not have to mean thousands.  There's a lot of engineering in highly specialized equipment that may sell in orders of a few dozen to a few hundred pieces - and obviously it sells for rather high prices or no one would make money doing it.  Such industries are focused on meeting the need rapidly, not on spending months getting every last dollar out of the BOM.

Comment: @reemrevnivek - I think you and I are working in completely different worlds.  When I refer to a production part, it's anything that gets released to a customer, and it can be in quantities from 1 to 20, not tens of thousands, thousands, or even hundreds.  I could care less if I could reduce a part from $50 to 5 dollars, if that means I'll have to spend an extra 3 months on development.  I also don't mind if someone copies the code.

Comment: You've brought up really good points, though, and I value your input.  I think your answer was a little extreme and you are clearly opinionated on this subject, but I can distill the key points from it.

Comment: @Dave - Sorry, I consciously tried to make it not opinionated or extreme.  This is what it looks like after a few re-readings and edits :P.  However, I stand by my statement that the word 'production' means (in every context I've operated in, which is mainly as an automotive OEM supplier) thousands of parts.  Can you imagine opening your hood and seeing an Arduino hacked into your fan controller?  No, and for good reason.  I tried to give a few of those reasons.

Comment: @reemrevinek - haha! no offense taken.  I was hoping to get a lot of viewpoints with this question.  My environment is totally different.  We sell a few customized products that are quite expensive, so a part like an embedded board is okay if it costs more, and offsets the development time.  I'm using the Netduino right now only for prototyping concepts, but then it occurred to me that we could probably put it into the product, since it's just used with a display controller anyway.  I certainly agree that it is better / more professional to have a custom board, but wanted to hear opinions.

Comment: @reemrevnivek I could easily imagine seeing an arduino in an enclosure under the hood of a race car.

Comment: @Chris I am thinking about putting one in mine, but only for displaying sensor data, not something like engine management.  :)

Comment: @Chris & Dave: Same here. I'm restoring an old Corvette and in the process of putting additional sensors and analyzers in. I'm using FEZ Panda (Arduino compatible) test equipment and I'm considering using a mini version of one of the dev boards "in production". I see nothing wrong with that application and wouldnt even see anything wrong in selling them. Of course, mass quantity production would be limited due to the reasons reemrevnivek listed.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I can't say I agree with your disdain for tools and development environment. Paranoia of Microsoft going out of business or not supporting the .Net framework in the future is undue.

Comment: BTW...the .Net Micro Framework 4 is open source

Comment: @Kihoffer - are the ports to a given target board all required to be open source, or only the upstream distribution from Microsoft?

Comment: @Chris Stratton, the answer to that question is No, individual porters are not required to open source their port. The .NET MF core source is open sourced by Microsoft and anyone is free to port it to a particular target - this often means adding their own proprietary libraries as well.  A good example here would be GHI's Fez offerings versus Secret Lab's Netduino. One has chosen to close source their port and load it on from the factory while the other has chosen to open source their port. It is a significant effort to port .NET MF and some have chosen to protect what they've added.

Comment: @Jon - it's of limited support benefit for the upstream .Net framework to be open source if the actual implementations running on a particular board happen not to be.

Answer (score 4):

I have use an Arduino board in a product (not large scale production) and I wouldn't do it again.  The Arduino boards are geared towards a very closed ecosystem (in the non open-source software meaning of the word).  For instance, if you 'step out' of the Arduino ecosystem by needing to use a pin that isn't brought out to a header on the development board, you immediately lose all the benefits of the Arduino.  You have to modify the board to bring the pin to an existing header or add a new header somehow.  This likely means you won't be able to use any existing shields or possibly even the software libraries for the Arduino. That's most of the benefit of the board gone. I have had to do this with an Arduino Mega.

Also, the boards are huge and not easy to integrate with other PCBs  I made the main board for my application equivalent to a shield for the Arduino Mega that had mounting holes for the enclosure I chose.  So I just plugged the Arduino Mega into the headers I put on my board.  However, this was a lot of up and down size to accommodate, and there was a lot of wasted space due to the size of the development board.  I didn't need half of what was on there and it only took up room.  This required me to have a larger PCB and enclosure than I otherwise would have needed.  That's wasted money.

Comment: The arduino (and even arm-powered) designs are simple enough that if you are going to be making a PCB suitable for digital logic to accessorize them, you might as well just include the processor too.  They'd be more tempting if you were not going to be making a PCB at all, or were doing it single sided or in a special analog or RF technology where you didn't want digital parts on that board, and having to do a controller board too would be more expense than buying (and even reworking) them.

Comment: Chris-definitely.  Everyone should know that if you're making a PCB yourself there's little point in adding an Arduino board as opposed to just recreating one on your PCB.

Comment: If Arduino environment becomes a limiting factor, you can always use any other AVR compiler like GCC, BASCOM, AvrCo and produce firmware that will live on the same Arduino board...

Answer (score 4):

Arduinos &co are *prototyping and evaluation platforms*. As such, they are simply not economically viable as a basis for even relatively small production runs. They're great for education and mocking up ideas, but a product would sink very quickly if it had to carry the cost of a ready-made sub-assembly that was not optimal in its final use.

It would be far better to create a new board including required elements of the 'duino and any ancillary circuitry than to have the cost of two boards and the risk of failing connections.

With regard to Visual Studio and anything .net, I wouldn't touch them with someone else's. Go for something platform and manufacturer agnostic - kind of in the spirit of the Arduino project itself.

Comment: I still believe it all depends on the cost of your product.  Let's say that it's possible to create something really compelling with the *duino, and it's a small part of a 1M USD project, and you're only ever going to sell 3 of them.  Why wouldn't that be economically viable?  Would you prefer to spend thousands on development for something that's going to be used twice?

Comment: Regarding the .NET comment, I frequently run into people that don't like to use Visual Studio and / or .NET just because.  I personally don't get it.  Visual Studio is by far one of the best IDEs I have ever used.  I am admittedly biased towards Microsoft tools because they let me get my work done quickly, and 99% of the time, they just work.  Although I should really learn to use development boards with an ICE, I definitely appreciate the ease of using a familiar environment that lets me set breakpoints during debugging.  AFAIK you can't do that with Arduino.

Comment: WRT your first comment, I did say relatively small runs. I would see a run of three large budget developments as ongoing prototypes. I imagine the client would, too. In that situation, I would happily use an Arduino.

Comment: The MS/.net thing is based on personal experience. Over the last twenty or so years I've used almost every platform out there. The biggest headaches have invariably come from MS products. MS seem to assume that their way is the only proper way. Currently I'm using OS X, Ubuntu and Windows 7, all in a development environment. Guess which one I have to reboot (at all)?

Comment: @Dave - You can do on-chip debugging if you have JTAG support with OpenOCD and GDB.  You're right, the Arduino doesn't support this.  You'll need a processor with JTAG: Most ARM variants work with OpenOCD. The Netduino does have this, but that's because it's leveraging the JTAG support in the ARM processor it's using.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I definitely need to learn how to use JTAG.  Do you know of any micros that support it with a relatively cheap interface and a gcc/gdb toolchain that's easy to set up?  I know you mentioned ARM, but I don't know if those JTAG tools are inexpensive or not.  Any recommendations are welcome as I like to keep up with the latest options.

Comment: The ATMegas used on Arduino support debugging via debugwire- not sure if the Arduino reset pin hardware is compatible but if not wouldn't take much to hack as it's only one pin. Another potentially major issue about using other people's boards is if you care about stuff lie EMC, FCC cretification etc.

Comment: @Dave - breakpoint target debugging is hardly unique to Visual Studio, it's really a feature of most IDE's and embedded tools once you get away from the smallest and most resource-constrained target processors, for example any platform that can handle gdb/gdbserver will work with any IDE that can speak GDB's command language.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I realize that.  I think it's just that I've never experienced anything this easy before.  You just have to understand that my background is not embedded programming (and setting up gcc / gdb toolchains), and getting the embedded tools in the past (on linux, for example) has really gotten the best of me.  But in the PC s/w development world, Visual Studio will spoil you.

Comment: @Dave - until you want to do something it can't do, or run on or develop for a platform it can't handle.  But I agree the OSS tools can be a real pain to set up perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking there is nothing wrong with using off-the-shelve products. We all do this at some level, I guess the Arduino-haters don't design their own chips, even tough at *some higher volume level* that would make economic sense.

It always boils down to cost, schedule and quality (and maybe long-term availability too). If an Arduino meets these criteria better than a custom board, the choice is a no-brainer.

The difficult part is to get the right figures, especially for your volume. But using the correct figures and little math will give you the break-even volume for the choice between uising let's say the Arduino versus a custom board. If that is way beyond what you expect, or way below, the choice is easy. So forget all advices that say either "by all means use an Arduino" or "always go for a custom board", they are both locked into a mindset that belongs to a specific volume level. Do your own calculations.

Note that I have no specific knowledge of the Arduino. You will have to decide for yourself whether it meets for instance your quality requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Custom made boards are nice if you have a budget for this and production big enough to justify the work. Otherwise you stick with products of the shelf, like Arduino, Netduino, Fez Domino, and [SBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-board_computer) boards (like in PC104 and various ITX formats). Making custom AVR/Arduino board is not too complex, but heavy modifications to Netduino or even designing (and later supporting) some linux board (like Gumstix) need a specialist(s) and cost tens of thousands of dollars and more. If you want to have most of the hard work done by someone else, and you want to customize just some parts of it, then [module](http://www.xduino.com/hardware/) is the [magic](http://www.mme-berlin.de/arm9-modul/index.htm) [word](http://www.developmentboard.net/index.php/productdetail/core+boards/ARM9/SAMSUNG/S3C2440/CSKY2440-v2/info/1) for you.

Comment: I definitely agree with you, but at some point you still need a PCB.  I have enough skill to make one for *duino and others to create a simple PCB for breaking out signals and power, so at least that's still pretty cheap.

Comment: It is cheap if you don't need thousands, and if you need more power then modules like the one from above link is nice, too. Beware that you will probably have to deal your self with brown out detection, power disturbance if writing to eeprom, reliable power supply, and many other things that depend on your specific application.